# Codeigniter routing on shared host

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, hosting

I am trying to move my codeigniter application from my WAMP installation to a shared host (justhost) for the first time.

In my public_html folder I have included all of the folders and files for my application. So for example I see my "application" folder when I open public_html in my file manager.

I have a controller "Lander" which I have set to be the default via `$route['default_controller'] = 'Lander'`

When I go to www.mywebsite.com I do see the view that gets loaded from the Lander controller. The problem is that within that view I have a link `<a href="login">Log in</a>` that, when I'm running on WAMP, opens the login controller, which is in the same folder as the Lander controller. When I click this link from the hosted site the URL goes to www.mywebsite.com/Login, but I get 404 not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; # remove index.php
```

**`.htaccess` should be**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and Links should be

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>login">Log in</a>
```

> There **should be a controller** call `login` or in **routes you should define**

Comment: what is your site URL ??

Comment: I have added your htaccess but I'm still not able to find my login controller

Comment: I think it's working now. I tried a couple of things, including renaming my controller to Login instead of login, and I'm getting results.

Comment: @David happy to help :)